# Insert random codes between images loaded from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("bravo");
    $res=mysql_query("select * from coisas");

?>
<div>
<?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">";

    }
?>
</div>
```

And i need to show an adsense code in random position between the images, can anyone help-me?

Comment: What do you mean "in random positions"?  What are you even trying to do?

Comment: Just add the adsense code after the echo in the while?

Comment: Do you only want the ad to show up once? or do you want it to have a chance to appear between every image?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 2):

Add some code in the while:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
   echo "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">";
   echo "--- adsense code here---";
}
```

Which will inject it after every image.

Or if you really want to place it in totally random positions:

```
$chanceOfAdsense = 35; // 35% chance of adsense appearing between any given images

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
   echo "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">";

   if (mt_rand(0,99) < $chanceOfAdsense) {
      echo "--- adsense code here---";
   }
}
```

Comment: and to load the adsense code after every 4 images?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki If you wanted to do that, just have a counter in your while that fetches the array. You would do something like `if ($counter % 4 == 0) { echo "adsense code"; }` instead of the if-statement with the `mt_rand()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Build an output array from the while loop, then count the number of values in it. Calculate a random number with rand() using count(array) and then iterate over the output array, with an if statement for when the index matches the random number.

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("bravo");
    $res=mysql_query("select * from coisas");

?>
<div>
<?php
    $output_array = array();
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

      $output_array[] = "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">";

    }

    //If you want the image to appear closer to middle, use fractions of $output_array
    //EG: rand(count($output_array)/3, count($output_array)*2/3));
    $rand_key = rand(0, count($output_array)-1);

    foreach ($output_array as $key => $img) {
       if ($key == $rand_key) {
           //echo your adsense code
       }
       echo $img;
    }
?>
</div>
```